# Toggling visibility of a span inside li element fails

Tags: jquery

I have a list `<li>` that i have made and in it i have some spans. This is the html

```
<ul class="tracking_nav nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">  
<li class="tracking_list_type" style=".tracking_list_type:hover{background-color:none !important}">  
<a href="#"><span class="topinfo"><span class="number_plates"><img src="u_online.gif" />Number 10</span></span><span class="moving_status">76 moving</span><br/><span class="link_text">Brother David Cameroon</span></a><span class="linkso"><a href="">Tracking</a><a href="">Playback</a><a href="">Commands</a></span></li>     
<li class="tracking_list_type" style=".tracking_list_type:hover{background-color:none !important}">  
<a href="#"><span class="topinfo"><span class="number_plates"><img src="u_online.gif" />Number 10</span></span><span class="moving_status">76 moving</span><br/><span class="link_text">Brother David Cameroon</span></a><span class="linkso"><a href="">Tracking</a><a href="">Playback</a><a href="">Commands</a></span></li> 
<li class="tracking_list_type" style=".tracking_list_type:hover{background-color:none !important}">  
<a href="#"><span class="topinfo"><span class="number_plates"><img src="u_online.gif" />Number 10</span></span><span class="moving_status">76 moving</span><br/><span class="link_text">Brother David Cameroon</span></a><span class="linkso"><a href="">Tracking</a><a href="">Playback</a><a href="">Commands</a></span></li> 
<li class="tracking_list_type" style=".tracking_list_type:hover{background-color:none !important}">  
<a href="#"><span class="topinfo"><span class="number_plates"><img src="u_online.gif" />Number 10</span></span><span class="moving_status">76 moving</span><br/><span class="link_text">Brother David Cameroon</span></a><span class="linkso"><a href="">Tracking</a><a href="">Playback</a><a href="">Commands</a></span></li> 
</ul>
```

By default,i have hidden `<span class="linkso"><a href="">Tracking</a><a href="">Playback</a><a href="">Commands</a></span>` and the only way to display it is by clicking `<li class="tracking_list_type">....</li>` which houses `<span class="linkso"><a href="">Tracking</a><a href="">Playback</a><a href="">Commands</a></span>`
Once li is clicked i want the div with the class `linkso` to be displayed and if i click another li,i want that li's `linkso` to be displayed and any other `linkso` visible to be hidden.

Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/codebreaker87/eoo87zkk/13/

How can i fix my code?.

Comment: *How can i fix my code?.* - Fix the formatting first.

Comment: Are you really using jQuery 1.4.4? You really should update it as it's now over 6 years out of date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from jQuery 1.4, which does not have the `on` method, you have other issues like

`.linkso` is a descendant of the `li`, so you need to use `.find()`

```js
jQuery(function() {
  $(".tracking_list_type").click(function() {
    var $linkso = $(this).find(".linkso").toggle();
    $(".tracking_list_type .linkso").not($linkso).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.moving_status {
  float: right;
  color: #76EE00;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.linkso {
  margin-left: 13px;
  display: none;
}
.topinfo {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.linkso > a {
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tracking_nav nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
  <li class="tracking_list_type" style=".tracking_list_type:hover{background-color:none !important}">
    <a href="#"><span class="topinfo"><span class="number_plates"><img src="u_online.gif" />Number 10</span></span><span class="moving_status">76 moving</span><br/><span class="link_text">Brother David Cameroon</span></a><span class="linkso"><a href="">Tracking</a><a href="">Playback</a><a href="">Commands</a></span>
  </li>
  <li class="tracking_list_type" style=".tracking_list_type:hover{background-color:none !important}">
    <a href="#"><span class="topinfo"><span class="number_plates"><img src="u_online.gif" />Number 10</span></span><span class="moving_status">76 moving</span><br/><span class="link_text">Brother David Cameroon</span></a><span class="linkso"><a href="">Tracking</a><a href="">Playback</a><a href="">Commands</a></span>
  </li>
  <li class="tracking_list_type" style=".tracking_list_type:hover{background-color:none !important}">
    <a href="#"><span class="topinfo"><span class="number_plates"><img src="u_online.gif" />Number 10</span></span><span class="moving_status">76 moving</span><br/><span class="link_text">Brother David Cameroon</span></a><span class="linkso"><a href="">Tracking</a><a href="">Playback</a><a href="">Commands</a></span>
  </li>
  <li class="tracking_list_type" style=".tracking_list_type:hover{background-color:none !important}">
    <a href="#"><span class="topinfo"><span class="number_plates"><img src="u_online.gif" />Number 10</span></span><span class="moving_status">76 moving</span><br/><span class="link_text">Brother David Cameroon</span></a><span class="linkso"><a href="">Tracking</a><a href="">Playback</a><a href="">Commands</a></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```